# Timeout issue using codefirststoredprocs in MVC5/EF 6. Error reading from stored proc dbo.[...]: Timeout expired

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, timeout, cfstoredproc

In order to process nearly 70K records at a time, I use codefriststoredprocs 2.5.0 with my application. With few records everything works fine but with large set of data, I receive "The wait operation timed out" exception.
I tried modifying default command timeout value from 30 seconds to 600 seconds in following manner.

```
//Previous approach
   ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)this.db).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;

//New approach for EF 6
this.db.Database.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

but still receives connection timeout message after 30 seconds. I also modified web.config setting Connection timeout value to 600 seconds (I know it is a different thing than command timeout value but give it a go). 
I feel like the issue is with codefirststoredprocs library that while executing stored procedure change command timeout value to default. Is there any way to fix this issue or should I go to alternate approach of using stored procedures with my application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would like to thanks `CodeFirstStoredProcs` team for their effort and collaboration to solve this issue.

I guess, as mentioned earlier, the command timeout values might have been defaulted to 30 seconds inside `CodeFirstStoredProcs` library.

With their new release (version 2.6),they have added ‘command timeout’ parameter to the `CallStoredProc<>`  method, that helped me set a default value for commandtimeout 
and finally solved my issue.

To process nearly 70K records in my case, I set `CommandTimeout = 0`  to `CallStoredProc<>`  method. This adds an infinite waiting time to execute stored
procedure.

Thanks once again for `CodeFirstStoredProcs` team. :)

Comment: Constructor is `new StoredProc<Model>() { commandTimeout = 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when changing to EF6.

Your might be setting the CommandTimeout in wrong place. Try setting the CommandTimeout where you are creating the context, like this:

```
var context = new Entities();
context.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

Also check if the CommandTimeout was changed with your approach after creating the context. If so then there might be some other issue.